# Comments - Convert HTML to character entities

Tags: comments

I wanted all my private messages and comments HTML text to be converted to character entities.

Fortunately for private messages, I was able to do it by setting a configuration via the Control Panel

Members -> Preferences -> Private Messaging Preferences -> HTML Formatting in Private Messages

Looking for a similar configuration for comments in the Control Panel, I can't seem to find any.

Is there a configuration for this specifically for comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's generally located in the General Channel Settings, and would need to be set per channel, which makes sense, since comments can be turned on and off per channel. See image:

[image]